# Handling spatial data in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, spatial

I have a database with a field for spatial data and a cakephp interface for it.  In MySQL I can save the data by doing:

INSERT INTO nodes (Location) VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT(42.450071 -76.487664)'))

How can I make Cake take the latitude and longitude from a web form and insert it in this manner?  I made a model that reads spatial data but I can't figure out how to make it write in spatial format.

Thanks for any insight.

-Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tricky to find in the manual unless you know what to look for, but this should help you:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1027/query

e.g. something along the lines of:

```
$gLat = 42.450071;
$gLong = -76.487664;
$this->Node->query("INSERT INTO nodes (Location) VALUES (GeomFromText('POINT({$gLat} {$gLong})'))");
```

Comment: Aha - looks good.  So I must make a field in the view that uploads the variables to $gLat and $gLong.  Just doing 

echo $form->input('gLat');

won't do it though.  I looked in the book but is there a way to make the form input go to a variable readable by the controller rather than automatically entered into the db?

Comment: $this->data will contain all of the form data. Try debug($this->data); in your controller.