# Saving spatial data in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, spatial, cakephp-2.3

I have a problem saving spatial data in CakePHP with saveAll(). I really dont want to write the query manually ([Handling spatial data in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598834/handling-spatial-data-in-cakephp)) because there are number of models being saved.

Also I read this [CakePHP and MySQL Spatial Extension](http://muxe.org/blog/cakephp-and-mysql-spatial-extension) but when I try to do the same, `$db->expression()` returns an stdClass.

This is the returned object printed out:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => expression
    [value] => GeomFromText('POINT(48.18879 18.527579999999944)')
)
```

If I use this object the way it is used in [CakePHP and MySQL Spatial Extension](http://muxe.org/blog/cakephp-and-mysql-spatial-extension) and try to save it with saveAll() I get this error:

**Error**: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
File: /www/s/t/u47728/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php
Line: 2221

If I use the value property, it gets escaped in the query so it becomes just a string. Then I get this error:

**Error**: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Does saveAll() suport expressions?

**UPDATE**

Apparently the same applies to save() function and others.... Also saveField()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

convert this line :

```
$this->data['Report']['position'] = $db->expression("GeomFromText('POINT(" . 
    $this->data['Report']['lat'] . " " . $this->data['Report']['lng'] . ")')");
```

to :

```
$this->data['Report']['position'] = (object) $db->expression("GeomFromText('POINT(" .
     $this->data['Report']['lat'] . " " . $this->data['Report']['lng'] . ")')");
```

It should work.

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it didn't work, however typecasting an object was the key so I tried `$this->data['Report']['position'] = (object) $db->expression("GeomFromText('POINT(" . $this->data['Report']['lat'] . " " . $this->data['Report']['lng'] . ")')");` and it worked. So marking your answer as accepted anyways because it lead me to the solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You should also change the order of your data.

The right way is: **POINT(longitude latitude)**

Couldn't comment on the right answer as i haven't enough reputation.