# PHP PDO Insert Longditude / latituded in Mysql and check if exists before insert

Tags: mysql, pdo, latitude-longitude, point

I am trying to insert geolocations correctly into my mysql db so that I may run a query to get all items within a set radius.

my db is set up like so:
     --id (integer pk)
     --latlon (point spatial index)

and my function which checks if the geolocation exists and if not inserts looks like this:

```
function addGeoLocation($long,$lat,$deal_id,$db)
{
    if($long != '' && $long > 0){

        $latlon = 'POINT('.$lat .' ' .$long.')';

        $locs = $db->row("SELECT id FROM geolocations WHERE latlon = :latlon",array("latlon"=>$latlon));
        if(!$locs)
        {
             $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO geolocations set latlon = PointFromText(:latlon)",array("latlon"=>$latlon));
            $location_id = $db->lastInsertId();
        }
        else
        {
            $location_id = $locs['id']; 
        }

        $locs_pivot = $db->row("SELECT id FROM dailydeals_geolocations WHERE dailydeal_id = :deal_id AND geolocation_id = :location_id",array("deal_id"=>$deal_id,"location_id"=>$location_id));

        if(!$locs_pivot)
        {
            $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO dailydeals_geolocations (geolocation_id,dailydeal_id) VALUES(:location_id,:deal_id)",array("location_id"=>$location_id,"deal_id"=>$deal_id));

        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I try I just cannot get it to insert the geo I just keep getting this error:

```
Unhandled Exception. <br />SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 
1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Any help would be greatly received

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This error of MySQL means that you are inserting a number value that is larger than the maximum allowed value for that column type.

I think you need to check again what you are doing at "*PointFromText*" or you can change your column type to be larger enough to hold the given value.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply I have changed PointFromText() to GeomFromText() that should format the value to fit the field but it still throws the same error so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the type of latlon column ?

Comment: Also take a look on the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647641/saving-spatial-data-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

my code actually works this issue is I have a latlon field also in the locations table which I manually populate with the lat lon values because this field is null on import it throws the error  :o)